How can the sharing action be modified?
I guess that this needs some explanation, because words like "share" can mean so many different things when it comes to an operating system. So, this is not about SAMBA or anything like it. When I open a file like a PDF in the default document viewer (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS) and I click on the little hamburger menu, then on top I have three little buttons for printing, resizing, and well ... sharing. This is the sharing function that I want to talk about. When I click on it, it opens a compose window in my default mail application. So far so good. But I do not know, where this is configured and how I can modify it.
I would like to change it, so that each time when I click that button, the new mail has the filename in the subject of the composer window. As I do this very often, it would help me to reduce unnecessary typing time.
Can you help me, where I do have to look for this?
Best regards
Martin
